# Images getting cached and eating up my Heap Space

Tags: java, image, caching, image-caching

This question is a result of the answers provided to me for my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229091/my-app-is-constantly-running-full-gc).

I was asked to use Eclipse MAT to investigate what is eating up my heap. Below are my observations (Top Consumers):

```
class sun.awt.SunToolkit                                 333.7 MB
com.tennisearth.service.impl.CacheManagerServiceImpl     136 MB
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet                     91.5 MB
```

I have already fixed the issue with `CacheManageServiceImpl`, but require help with `SunToolkit`.

Below is the code that creates an Image object (which internally uses `SunToolkit.imgCache`)

```
Image img = new ImageIcon(imagePath).getImage();
int imageWidth = img.getWidth(null);
int imageHeight = img.getHeight(null);
```

Plz note that the Image object is only being created to get the width / height of the image which is required later in some logic.

Is there a way to disable `SunToolkit` image caching? Better yet, is there a way to clear this cache? Or is there a better way I can retrieve this information?

BTW for your reference, I am using the below command to run jboss (plz note the heap size arguments):

```
java -Dprogram.name=run.sh -server -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/data1/logs/jboss/GC.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dorg.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/java/jboss-4.2.2.GA/bin/native -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/java/jboss-4.2.2.GA/lib/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/java/jboss-4.2.2.GA/bin/run.jar:/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_06/lib/tools.jar org.jboss.Main -c default -b <IP_ADDRESS> -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=1
```

Sumit

Comment: there are a *lot* of issues in Java related to images and image caching.  The infamous *flush()* workaround around API defects spring to mind.  Nullifying images is not always enough: sometimes you need to call *flush()* yourself and it simply makes no sense.  If it's on a server, I'd just get that width/height info by running externally ImageMagick's *identify* command.  It's a bit of a pain to run an external process but then loading an image just to get it's width/height on a server is quite heavyweight too.

Comment: another option... We were batch processing all our pictures and putting the widht/height info directly in the picture's filename: *mypic.jpg* becomes *mypic640x480.jpg*.  Then we simply extracted the (w,h) from the filename...

Comment: if you want to Google on this issue, here's an interesting quote: *We have seen the flush issue on other platforms than OS X, so I think the "proper" fix needs to be put in by Sun, by implementing finalize on ToolkitImage to force a flush before GC reclaims the image. Has anyone reported this to Sun?*

Comment: I ship a Java app on hundreds of different Windows/OS X making heavy use of images and I can tell: there **are** definitely bugs left and right and we're seeing OutOfMemory errors that should never have happened had these APIs been correctly designed/implemented by Sun.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, using an external command is not an option and I would also like to make use of the internal cache mechanism to speed up the process. As per Jorn's comment, the cache expiry is handled by the JVM itself so I am not to worry about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image cache seems to be implemented by a class named [SoftCache](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=de#ih5hvYJNSIA/src/share/classes/sun/misc/SoftCache.java), its documentation states the following:

> A memory-sensitive implementation of the `Map` interface.
>
> A `SoftCache` object uses [java.lang.ref.SoftReference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html)
>   to implement a memory-sensitive hash map.  If the garbage
>   collector determines at a certain point in time that a value object in a
>   `SoftCache` entry is no longer strongly reachable, then it may
>   remove that entry in order to release the memory occupied by the value
>   object.  All `SoftCache` objects are guaranteed to be completely
>   cleared before the virtual machine will throw an
>   `OutOfMemoryError`.

So I would not worry about the memory taken by this cache since it will get cleared automatically when the memory is needed elsewhere.

**Edit:** After reading the comments by [SyntaxT3rr0r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257356/syntaxt3rr0r?tab=activity), I think it could still be worthwhile to call `flush` on the Image. If this is part of a larget method you could also set image to null or refactor so it goes out of scope sooner.

Another possibility would be to try the ImageIO Api to retrieve the width and height. This should be possible by getting a [ImageReader for the image type](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#getImageReadersByMIMEType(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Thanks alot for your clarification. Glad am not to worry about this anymore :)

Comment: Just saw your edit, I still would like to use image caching to speed up the process of creating the image object. I believe flushing the image wont be able to use this cache. Right?

Comment: @Sumit, I don't know exactly which caches are flushed by that call. If you repeatedly query the width and height for the same image path it might also make sense to implement a simple cache yourself, like a `Map<String, WidthAndHeightBean>`. That would avoid the need to recreate the image once the imgCache is cleared up by the gc.

Comment: I have the exact problem that the image cache is keeping very large images in memory for slightly too long.   I try to load another large image and it gets out of memory as the GC doesnt seem to run in time.   I.e we load 40 or 50 Mb images and convert them to smaller images.  Forcing the GC via jconsole between each image load fixes it but during normal operation it sometimes gets out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible your Image object remains in scope for long periods of time?  For example, if it's contained in the outer scope of a block of code that runs for long periods of time, it may not be properly garbage collected.

Sometimes (in rare cases), it's beneficial to explicitly set your Image object reference to null.  This would be true in the case I mentioned above.  See the following question for more info: [Does assigning objects to null in Java impact garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449409/does-assigning-objects-to-null-in-java-impact-garbage-collection)